# Should SQL commands be combined in this case

Tags: sql, c#-4.0

I have following c# code:

Basically i am selecting one row from TableA/Database1 and inserting it in TableA/Database2.

Then i am again opening connection and selecting multiple rows from TableB/Database1 (using newID retrieved from TableA/Database1) and inserting in TableB/Database2.

My question is it right approach to do this? Or should these be combined? If these should be combined, can anyone please show me best way to achieve this?

```
int newID = 0;
using (var con1 = new SqlConnection(conString1))
using (var con2 = new SqlConnection(conString2))
{
    con1.Open();
    con2.Open();
    using (var selectCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect, con1))
    {
        using (var reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            try
            {
                if (reader != null)
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        using (var insertCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlInsert, conTarget))
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                            {
                                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                                    "@" + reader.GetName(i), reader[i]);
                            }
                            newID = (int)insertCommand.ExecuteScalar();
                        }
                    }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            finally
            {
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am passing newID as value for one of the selects example:

`Select Id, student as newID, Class from Student where class = 10`

```
using (var con1 = new SqlConnection(ConString1))
{
    con1.Open();               
    var cmd = new SqlCommand(query , con1);
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    using (var con2 = new SqlConnection(conString2))
    {
        con2.Open();

        using (var sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(conString2))
        {
            sbc.BulkCopyTimeout = 2000;
            sbc.DestinationTableName = "student";
            try
            {
                if (reader != null) 
                    sbc.WriteToServer(reader);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            finally
            {                            
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: both the databases are in the same server?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is something like:

1. Open connection1 and select all the data that you need from the first database. Store this data in some object.
2. Open connection 2 and update the second database based on the values stored in the objects created in step 1.

That will enable you to use one connection to each database and accomplish the same thing that you are doing above.

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: How can i run two sql commands in this case at one time? Can i use using statement and still run two commands under one connection? Can you show me some code?